# Не заходит в биос на ноутбуке

Tags: ноутбук

При заходе в биос на ноутбуке, при зажатии клавиш, при помощи кнопки сбоку, а так же в самом виндовсе через shift, появляется чёрный экран, некая пустая консоль и ничего не происходит. Случилось это после настройки биоса, где я поменял UEFI на Legacy, что видимо и привело к проблеме.

Comment: F2, del не нужно зажимать. Нужно нажать несколько раз в начале загрузки

Comment: Сбросьте все, в чем проблема? Как сбросить в интернете инфы валом, в плоть до разбора и замыкания контактов.